# How to filter a sorted RDD by taking top N rows

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have 2 key-value pair RDD's A and B that I work with. Let's say that B has 10000 rows and I have sorted B by its values:

```
B = B0.map(_.swap).sortByKey().map(_.swap)
```

I need to take top 5000 from B and use that to join with A. I know I could do:

```
B1 = B.take(5000)
```

or

```
B1 = B.zipWithIndex().filter(_._2 < 5000).map(_._1)
```

It seems that both will trigger computation. Since B1 is just an intermediate result, I would like to have it not trigger real computation. Is there a better way to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no other way to achieve that using RDD. But you can leverage the dataframe to achieve the same.

1. First convert your RDD to a dataframe.
2. Then limit the dataframe to limit 5000 value.
3. Then you can pick the new RDD from the dataframe.
4. Upto this point no calculation will be triggered by spark.

Below is a sample proof of concept.

```
  def main(arg: Array[String]): Unit = {
    import spark.implicits._
    val a =
      Array(
        Array("key_1", "value_1"),
        Array("key_2", "value_2"),
        Array("key_3", "value_3"),
        Array("key_4", "value_4"),
        Array("key_5", "value_5")
      )

    val rdd = spark.sparkContext.makeRDD(a)
    val df = rdd.map({
      case Array(key, value) => PairRdd(key, value)
    }).toDF()

    val dfWithTop = df.limit(3)
    val rddWithTop = dfWithTop.rdd
    // upto this point no computation has been triggered
    // rddWithTop.take(100) will trigger computation
  }

  case class PairRdd(key: String, value: String)
```